# Multiple validates with :on in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I have a doubt if there is multiple validate in a line if `:on` at last whether all the validation are applicable to the `:on` or only the last validation.

```
validate :trial_account, :limit_for_account, on: :check_trial
```

Whether only `limit_for_account` is validated on `check_trial` or both.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
validate :trial_account,     on: :check_trial
validate :limit_for_account, on: :check_trial
```